# Sign in problem with Play Games - Android Studio JAVA

Tags: java, android, sdk

I did exactly same thing that in google docs for Play Games Services Sign In v2. But whenever run my project in android studio,"isAuthenticated" variable is always set as "false". I find isAuthenticatedTask.isSuccessful() returns "true". But (isAuthenticatedTask.getResult().isAuthenticated()) returns "false" so "isAuthenticated" variable is going to be set as "false". That means I cannot sign in google play games. I used exact same code that provided by Google. Of course I did prerequests in the google docs. Sample code in my project:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Play Games Services
        PlayGamesSdk.initialize(this);

        GamesSignInClient gamesSignInClient = PlayGames.getGamesSignInClient(MainActivity.this);

        gamesSignInClient.isAuthenticated().addOnCompleteListener(isAuthenticatedTask -> {
            boolean isAuthenticated =
                    (isAuthenticatedTask.isSuccessful() &&
                            isAuthenticatedTask.getResult().isAuthenticated());

            if (isAuthenticated) {
                // Continue with Play Games Services
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Succesful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                // Disable your integration with Play Games Services or show a
                // login button to ask  players to sign-in. Clicking it should
                // call GamesSignInClient.signIn().

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        ///
}
```

It toasts (messages) "Fail!" always. I tried calling `gamesSignInClient.signIn()` on a button or inside "else". Nothing happened. There are some kind of logs that can be related to this. These:

```
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date for "MYPROJECT".  Requires 213000000 but found 202414023

W/GoogleApiManager: The service for com.google.android.gms.internal.games_v2.zzx is not available: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null, message=null}
```

Also I don't know why, Android Studio logs so many (maybe 50 times) of this in red color:

`E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5`

---

So, I tried almost everything. I did everything that in Google Play Console as well. Like, OAuth stuff. Publishing OAuth Consent, creating OAuth credentials and adding Project ID to games-ids.xml, even in strings.xml. Of course I created OAuth credential with my project SHA-1 signature. Why can't I sign in?

After this failure, I decided to implement Play Games Services v1 (Older One). I tried like explained in https://developers.google.com/games/services/v1/android/signin website (google docs).
But I didn't understand some explanations on it. Is there some kind of guide that is more explanative out there? Thanks!

Comment: Did you solve this issue ? Coz I'm currently facing the same one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

So I have the same problem, looking all over the internet and at last solve the issue.

Fill the Oauth Consent Screen https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent  and add a tester account, your gmail account you are using to test.

I don't know if it works for you, but it worked for me.

Comment: How is this answer not verified?
Thanks Nitish!

Comment: I didn't test this solution, but probably you are right, so I marked this post as right answer. Thank you! :)